# Problems with Python: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'

Tags: python

I'm starting to learn Python, but I'm having some problems, and I don't know exactly why. I have those two files, and as far as I know the problem is between the connection on both files, I think.
I have already browsed some other questions related to it, but none seems to work on my problem.

File1, MysqlDB.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import MySQLdb
class DB:
    def __init__(self, DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_CHARSET):
        self.host = DB_HOST
        self.port = DB_PORT
        self.name = DB_NAME
        self.user = DB_USER
        self.password = DB_PASSWORD
        self.charset = DB_CHARSET

    def get_conn(self):
        try:
            if self.conn is None:
                self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = self.host,
                                            port = self.port,
                                            db = self.name,
                                            user = self.user,
                                            passwd = self.password,
                                            charset = self.charset)
                return self.conn
        except:
            print("Can't connect to database")

    def get_cursor(self):
        try:
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            return self.cursor
        except:
            print("Can't define cursor (cursor == None)")

    def close_conn(self):
        if self.conn:
            self.conn.close()
```

File2, users.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import MysqlDB
from usersVO import UsersVO

class UsersDAO():
    def loginUser(self, tmpEmail, tmpPassword):
        OBJdb = MysqlDB.DB('127.0.0.1',3306,'root','','musica','utf8')
        OBJconn = OBJdb.get_conn()
        OBJcursor = OBJdb.get_cursor()

        queryLogin = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email_USER LIKE '{}' and password_USER LIKE '{}'".format(tmpEmail, tmpPassword)

        OBJcursor.execute(queryLogin)

Class = UsersDAO()
Class.loginUser('test@email.com','test')
```

When I try to test a login action on users.py, I always get this:

```
"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'"
```

Why is the OBJcursor getting the None value? How could I fix this?

Comment: As a side note, having a module with the same name as another module you're using except for the case (`MysqlDB` vs. `MySQLdb`) is a really bad idea—it will break on Windows, and may or may not break (in a nicely hard-to-predict way) on Mac.

Comment: Anyway, your `get_cursor` function has a bare `except:` that just prints `"Can't define cursor (cursor == None)"` and return `None`. Which means you have no idea what failed, only that something failed. If you want to debug it, either remove that so you get an exception, or change it to `except Exception as e:` and then print something useful, like `"Can't define cursor (cursor == None): {!r)".format(e)`.

Comment: You also have a serious problem inside `get_conn()`: the first time you call it, it may work—but every time you call it after that, it's going to return `None`, because the `return self.conn` only happens inside the `if self.conn is None:`.

Comment: Plus you're doing the same "hide the error to make this impossible to debug" `except:` thing in `get_conn()`, so it's quite possible that `get_conn()` failed, returned `None`, didn't set `self.conn`, and that's why `get_cursor` is also failing. But we have no way of knowing if that's what's happening.

Comment: One more side note: Don't use `str.format` to fill in a SQL query, use the database's query parameters. In other words, `queryLogin = "SELECT … LIKE %s and password_USER LIKE %s"`, then `OBJcursor.execute(queryLogin, (tmpEmail, tmpPassword)`. See [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) for more details on how, and [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/327/) for more on why.

Comment: Thanks man, I really appreciate the help, salf taught programming is really hard. But I still get the same error as before, but now I've got the Exception "DB instance has no attribute 'conn'". What could be causing this?

Comment: Probably what I said in a previous comment: `get_conn` is also failing, but you’re hiding that error.

Comment: It worked, thanks for all the help.